# Angular project error in production mode: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 65

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, production

I need help with this. Probably it is foolishness but, after hours of investigating, I cannot see the problem.
I have an angular 10 project. This is the backend (the api in php):

```
...
$result = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'code'   => 200,
        'data'   => $productos
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
});
```

It returns this json:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "code":200,
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "nombre":"Gazpacho tradicional",
            "marca":"Hacendado",
            "puntuacionYuca":"90\/100",
            "puntuacionCoco":"9\/10",
            "puntuacionMyReal":"Buen procesado",
            "mediaVagana":"9",
            "imagen":"gazpacho-hacendado.jpg",
            "supermercado":"Mercadona",
            "comentario":"Saludable en otras marcas"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have checked the json on several webs and it is valid.

This is the code in the angular service.ts:

```
getProductosVaganos(){
        return this._http.get(this.urlvaganos+'productos-vaganos').pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
    }
```

This is the code in the angular component.ts:

```
getProductosVaganos(){
        this._productoVaganoService.getProductosVaganos().subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result.code != 200){
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    this.productosVaganos = result.data;
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }
```

It works perfectly in development mode, in local. But when I compile the project and deploy it at public_html folder in the hosting, it returns this error at the component.ts function:

```
list.component.ts > getProductosVaganos() > error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 65
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at gd.json (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at O.project (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at O._next (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at O.next (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.s (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills.35a5ca1855eb057f016a.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.99255eee2d008be2c609.js:1)
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills.35a5ca1855eb057f016a.js:1)
    at a.runTask (polyfills.35a5ca1855eb057f016a.js:1)
```

The structure at public_html folder is the same as that in local.

I have tested the JSON.stringify() and the JSON.parse() methods but didn't find the solution.
I have tested too removing the .json() at the end of the line in the method of the service.ts. In this case, when I debug in chrome, in production, it enters inside the "result" at the component.ts method but the result.data element is "undefined".

I think the problem is between local and production since they have different languages, typescript in local, and the compiled one, which is javascript, in production, but I don`t know how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What do you see in the console when changing `pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()))` to `pipe(tap(response =>console.log(response)),map((response: any) => response.json()))`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I wrote earlier before working hours and I have finished now. I put this new parameter to pipe method:

`return this._http.get(this.urlvaganos+'productos-vaganos').pipe(tap(response =>console.log("tap: ", response)),map((response: any) => response.json()));`
Strangely, the console does not show this console.log.
It shows an error:

`ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at e.getProductosVaganos (main.043912fd7b9d49cb76b0.js:1)
    at e.getProductosVaganos (main.043912fd7b9d49cb76b0.js:1)
    at e.ngOnInit (main.043912fd7b9d49cb76b0.js:1)
    ...`

Comment: I put type any to tap response and it returns this: `gd {_body: "{↵  "success": false,↵  "error-codes": [↵    "inva…dona","comentario":"Saludable en otras marcas"}]}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: sd, …}
headers: sd {_headers: Map(13), _normalizedNames: Map(13)}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://vaganos.es/...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems `response` have full response. Try explicitly writing `{observe: 'body'}` as below.

```
getProductosVaganos(){
    return this._http.get(this.urlvaganos+'productos-vaganos', {observe: 'body'}).pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution doesn't compile. I declared "observe", but this is not de reason. Also, I tried with an observable object but the error remains. It says that "argument of type observe: string is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionArgs' ".
The summary of the error I have is:
If I convert response at the service (with .json()) it works in local but in production appears "Unexpected token ...".
If I remove this conversion, it does not work in local and in production enters to "result" paragraph of the component method but result.data is undefined.

Comment: Which angular version are you using? I guess you are using old version (4 or earlier).

Comment: This is the result of the ng version command: https://imgur.com/a/H5L5Yz3

Comment: I think I have to learn more about http vs httpclient and rxjs. Thanks N.F. for giving me some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I had some code for Google Recaptcha in the API, at the same file that contains the code to connect to the database. This google Recaptcha code was failing and it was throwing an error in JSON format. This piece of JSON was at the beginning of the response so the parser couldn't read correctly the part of the response data.
Commenting on this Recaptcha code the web runs ok.
Regards.